# Compare bytestrings in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Why in Erlang is `<<14>>` not the same as `<<"\r">>` if the character \r has the value 14?

If I do:

```
<<14>> = <<"\r">>.
```

I get

> ** exception error: no match of right hand side value <<"\r">>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong integer value; carriage return is decimal 13, not 14:

```
1>  <<13>> = <<"\r">>.
<<13>>
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't noticed that the value of \r was 13